# expression validation if a specific artifact is triggered azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have multiple artifacts and i would detect if one of these artifacts is triggered after build and deploy it to its respective agent

```
or(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], '$_Multi-Country/SSIS_FileDrop/Dev/DEV'))
```

Comment: You could use the [Artifact - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/artifacts/get?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1) from your build to get the target artifact.

Comment: Hi, how the solution shown below? Does it can help you achieve the condition you want successfully now? If yes, you can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Feel free to leave comment if you still facing any issue or puzzle:-)

Answer (score 0):

Since you can have multiple artifacts sources tied to one release definition, there's no such pre-defined variable exists could achieve the artifacts name.

Though artifacts source is not unique for release pipeline, but the **build id** which relevant with the artifacts is unique in release, and it can be got with one pre-defined variable `Build.Buildid`.

So, here agree with @MarTin's comment, you could use this [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/artifacts/get?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops-rest-5.0) to achieve the artifacts name firstly.

Below is the powershell script sample:

```
$url = "$($env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI)$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID/_apis/build/builds/$env:BUILD_BUILDID/artifacts?api-version=4.1"

$pipeline = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{
    Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
} -Method Get

Write-Host "artifactName:" ($artifactName = $Pipeline.value.name)

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=artifactName]$artifactName"
```

In this script, use environments `SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI` and `SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID` to get the current org name and project name. Also, the latest version that supports this api is `4.1`.

You can add this powershell task in the first step of the agent job. Then, you will be able to use the variable `artifactName` in the condition expression to validate whether the trigger artifact name is the specific one.